# Función para obtener información de un Tuit de Twitter

Tags: php, twitter-api

He creado una función en PHP donde, partiendo de la URL del tuit, obtengo los parámetros necesarios para poder embeberlo:

```
$titulo = "";
$fecha = "";
$nombrecompleto = "";
$nombre_usuario = "";


$url = "https://twitter.com/XboxQwik/status/884071790481256448";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$posts = $html->find('div[class=js-tweet-text-container]');
$titulo = $posts[0]->find('p',0);

$posts = $html->find('div[class=client-and-actions]');
$fecha = $posts[0]->find('span',0);

$posts = $html->find('span[class=FullNameGroup]');
$nombrecompleto = $posts[0]->find('strong',0);

$posts = $html->find('a[class=js-user-profile-link]');
$nombre_usuario = $posts[0]->find('span',1);


$codigo = generateRandomString();

//traducimos la imagen a código html
  $url_html = "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"es\"><p lang=\"es\" dir=\"ltr\">" . $titulo . "</p>&mdash; " . $nombrecompleto . " (" . $nombre_usuario . ") <a href=" . $url . ">" . $fecha . "</a></blockquote>";
```

Por lo general funciona bien, pero me he encontrado con un ejemplo que no me  devuelve los datos correctos y el tuit no consigue embeberse.

En este caso es una cuenta verificada, pero he probado con otras y no me da ese problema. En concreto de este usuario no me acepta ningún tuit, he probado con tuits suyos normales, con imágenes, videos y ninguno. Sólo me funcionan los tuits que él ha retuiteado.

No se me ocurre qué puede ser, los datos que recoge parecen estar bien también.

Answer (score 0):

por que no usas la api de twitter para ello es mas facil y te va a presentar menos errores en el futuro https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets

Me tome el pequeno tiempo de ver como funciona la api. Lo primero que debes hacer es leer esta pagina que nos provee twitter para entender como funciona la api, pero te lo resumire lhttps://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed.

Para obtener la informacion que necesitas la api nos devuelve un json, entonces por ejemplo si quieres ver un tweet en especifico, este seria un ejemplo.
https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F507185938620219395

Para modificarlo a tu gusto, debes especificar el usuario que en este caso seria %2FInterior, en el tuyo seria %2FXboxQwik y el status seria el tweet especifico que en el ejemplo seria %2F507185938620219395 pero en el tuyo seria %2F884071790481256448, al colocar la url en un navegador te descargara un json con la informacion del tweet y un html para postearlo en tu pagina. Respondeme si tienes preguntas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Veo un problema en todo esto, el uso es para un foro, no para publicar noticias por ejemplo o un blog, para ese cometido sí que voy manualmente al tweet y lo inserto, pero en un foro eso tiene que hacerse "por detrás". Lo que hago es permitir que los usuarios inserten el tweet entre las etiquetas [twitter] y [/twitter] y después proceso el texto para sacar las URLs. A partir de esas URLs tengo que obtener el tuit embebido.

Comment: por eso, realiza un pequeno script que remplaze la url que digite el usuario por la url para obtener el json, luego tomas el json y sacas el tweet, es incluso mas facil por que evitar mucho errores y te ahorras el html por que el json de lo incluye

Comment: No conozco JSON, tengo entendido que es Javascript básicamente, pero no me queda nada claro cómo tengo que recoger esa información si me genera un fichero JSON aparte. No sé cómo enlazarlos.

Comment: es facil, aca te dejo el link de como consumir un json https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: buscando un poco encontre este comentrario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url  *usa primero esta parte*  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'aca va la url del json');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->url;  si no funciona remplaza la penultima linea con $obj = $result